# Bash script to rename files in a directory

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to write a script that takes a directory as a command line parameter and iterates over the files in the directory changing their extension to `.bu` .

I thought this would work but I'm getting the output `'.bu' is not a target directory`

```
#!/bin/bash

for  f in $1; do
  mv "$f".* .bu
done
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
for f in *; do 
mv  "$f" "${f%.*}.bu"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Try that instead (assuming that `$1` is a folder):

```
for f in $1/*; do 
  mv "$f" "$f.bu"
done
```

Or use the rename utility:

```
rename -v 's/$/\.bu/' $1/*
```

Those commands add an extension. If you want to **change the existing extension** use that:

```
rename -v 's/\.[^\.]+$/\.bu/' $1/*
```

Comment: This appends the extension, it doesn't change it

Comment: @kos, OP said "takes a directory as a command line parameter ", so this is valid. I would only mention that if directory has space n the name, the OP needs to add double quotes, and i would ad double quotes to $1

Comment: @Serg "takes a directory as a command line parameter and iterates over the files in the directory changing their extension to `.bu`" so indeed OP wants to rename the files. Anyway +1 for the edit

Comment: @kos ah, I see now. Could that be substituted with `for f in $( ls $1 )` ?

Comment: @Serg Yes that would do

Answer (score 2):

Taking the KISS approach, I would recommend the following script

```
#! /bin/bash
cd $1;
rename 's/$/\.bu/' *
```

This will change working directory to the first parameter and then add a `.bu` extension to all files. This nullifies the need of for loop.

**EDIT:**
If you want to change the extension(instead of just adding it), you can try

```
rename 's/\..*$/\.bu/' *
```

command instead, in the above script.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` within a `bash` script is a reference to the fist argument passed from the command line, so you're actually trying to process a single folder.

There are answers already about how to solve your problem using pure `bash`, but I'd like to add that if you need a better filtering of what is being processed you can use `find` with some options to select the files to be processed:

```
find <path_to_directory> -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

<sub>*<path_to_directory> = path to the directory</sub>

Then loop over the list of files using `stdin` redirection:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read file
do
    rename 's/\..*/\.bu/' $file
done <<< $(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```